# "a role of" vs "roles of"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, singular-vs-plural, nouns, plural-forms

I am working on a scientific paper and would like to ask a question regarding the use of "a role of" vs "roles of". 
"Dendritic cells play critical roles in expansion and antitumor efficacy of infused T cells" or 
"Dendritic cells play a critical role in expansion and antitumor efficacy of infused T cells"
I wonder if I should use "critical roles of" because of "expansion and antitumor efficacy (plural)".
Any comments would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about grammar, it's about the number of roles that dentritic cells play.

If they play a single role - that is, perform a single function - stick to the singular **role**. It is not relevant whether this single function affects both **expansion** and **anti-tumour efficacy**.

If they play more than one, prefer the plural **roles**.

I would use a hyphen with **T-cells**

Comment: I see. Since the expansion of T-cells results in anti-tumor efficacy, I probably use "a role of" in this case. Thank you very much.